# What is the difference between opam pin and opam install, when to use one vs the other?

Tags: opam

I've obviously read the man pages but I still don't understand:

1. what the difference is
2. when I should use one vs the other
3. is it only about local versions or can I pin an online version with opam pin without having a local version?

---

I was partially told:

> As the documentation states, opam pin “allows local customisation of the packages in a given switch” (or “divert any package definition”, in the part you quoted). So, if you do not need to replace an official package definition with your own customization, just use opam install. But if you want to install an unofficial version of the package (e.g., an upstream branch, or your own changes), then use opam pin to override the source of the package.

> There is a bit of overlap between the two commands, since doing opam install camlpdf=1.7 and opam pin add camlpdf 1.7 achieve a similar effect. The difference is that the latter command creates a customized package that happens to match exactly the specified version, but you can later modify it using opam pin edit, e.g., to tweak the dependencies.

I also thought there was a difference in terms on not allowing the version to change no matter where it came from i.e. is it only about local versions or can I pin an online version with opam pin without having a local version?

---

man pages reference:

```
opam pin
This command allows one to pin a package to a specific version, but has been extended to allow much more than that.

The syntax is

opam pin add <package name> <target>
Where <target> may be a version, but also an URL of a local path, an archive, or even a git, mercurial or darcs repository. The package will be kept up-to-date with its origin on opam update and when explicitly mentioned in a command, so that you can simply run opam upgrade <package name> to re-compile it from its upstream. If the upstream includes opam metadata, that will be used as well.

opam pin add camlpdf 1.7                                      # version pin
opam pin add camlpdf ~/src/camlpdf                            # path
opam pin add opam-lib https://github.com/ocaml/opam.git#1.2   # specific branch or commit
opam pin add opam-lib --dev-repo                              # upstream repository
This is actually a powerful mechanism to divert any package definition, and can even be used to locally create packages that don't have entries in the repositories.

This can be used in conjunction with opam source to patch an existing package in a breeze:

opam source <package> --dev-repo --pin
cd <package>; hack hack hack;
opam upgrade .
```

for install

```
opam install
This command downloads, builds and installs packages along with all their dependencies. You can specify one or several packages, along with version constraints. E.g:

opam install lwt
opam install ocp-indent ocp-index.1.0.2
opam install "ocamlfind>=1.4.0"
```

page: https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Usage.html

related:

- [Is an opam pin project needed when one wants to install an opam project with opam reinstall or 'make'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74777579/is-opam-pin-project-needed-when-one-wants-to-install-a-opam-project-with-opam-re)
- https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-opam-pin-and-opam-install-when-to-use-one-vs-the-other/10942/6

Answer (score 2):

*opam install* and *opam pin* are the common two ways to manage the packages in the OCaml package manager, OPAM.

-*opam install* installs a latest version of package that is compatible with the
installed versions of other packages, from the repository and its
dependencies.

- *opam pin* allows us  to directly specify a version of a package and its dependencies. When you pin a package, OPAM will always use the specified version, even if a newer version is available. This is useful when you need an excat version of a package for compatibility reasons or any other reason.

Comment: for example to install a specific version: opam pin add coq-cheerios git+https://github.com/uwplse/cheerios.git#9c7f66e57b91f706d70afa8ed99d64ed98ab367

Comment: also the word `pin` suggests the pkg is force to remain the same for a while? Fixed? Is that throughout opam switches or how else?