# How do I install ocamlfind first properly before other opam packages without root permissions?

Tags: ocaml, coq, opam, dune

I was trying to install some coq packages with opam but have this hack:

```
# coq-equations seems to rely on ocamlfind for it's build, but doesn't
# list it as a dependency, so opam sometimes tries to install
# coq-equations before ocamlfind. Splitting this into a separate
# install call prevents that.
opam install -y coq-equations coq-metacoq coq-metacoq-checker coq-metacoq-template
```

I don't have root permisions so doing:

```
sudo apt-get install ocaml-findlib
```

doesn't work. How do I instal ocamlfind? Ideally the proper way with a package manager if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install `ocamlfind` independently in a first step

```bash
$ opam install ocamlfind
```

then install the packages that forgot their dependencies on `ocamlfind`:

```bash
$ opam install -y coq-equations coq-metacoq coq-metacoq-checker coq-metacoq-template
```